# Subset sum problem for a possible closest value to the target sum in Python for a really big list

Tags: python, time-complexity, subset-sum

I know this problem may have been asked by many. My challenge is that my list is long in length (say 100+) and my target may also be big. The recursive algorithm takes 10 minutes to complete. I need any one subset that makes it closest to the target-sum

My Code

```
combination_dict = {}

def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    if s == target:
        print("sum({})={}".format(partial, target))
        return
    if s >= target:
        partial.pop()
        combination_dict[sum(partial)] = partial
        return 

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])

if __name__ == "__main__":
lst = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100] #my actual list is really long len=100(max)
tgt = 434
subset_sum(lst, tgt)
closest_sum = max([i for i in combination_dict.keys()])
print("Closest possible sum={} and the combination is ={}".format(closest_sum, combination_dict[closest_sum]))
```

If my list length is > 20, it is stuck. I understand this has a time complexity of O(2^n)- but can someone please help me get this optimized to get my result in less than 30 seconds.
My list can have floats. And so be the target-sum.

Comment: The subset sum problem is NP Complete, so the time complexity would be `O(2^n)`. Please share the target, and list for which you want the result in < 30 secs

Comment: list =
[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
           100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
           100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
           100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
           100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100] and  target = 4834

Comment: Take a look at this - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221544163_An_Efficient_Approximation_Scheme_for_the_Subset-Sum_Problem

Comment: @RajKumarPandit That example is too simple: just check whether `len(set(numbers)) == 1` and if so, the problem is trivial.

Comment: @a_guest 
the example I gave above is not a kind of generic use case, I have other lists that don't have repeated elements but are long. Please assume that the elements in the list are not repeated always.

Comment: @RajKumarPandit I am not making that assumption, but I am free to include such a check in my algorithm which will solve your example case instantaneously. So you need to provide a realistic example for benchmarking. For example I could also include a check whether the target value can be reached by a sum of at most two values which is O(n).

Comment: @a_guest thanks for pointing this out. I do see that repeated values are making the list long and of which the distinct values are less. For instance, this is one of the realistic cases. List [69.972  ,104.958 ,69.972  ,104.958 ,104.958 ,44.78208,69.972  ,69.972  ,69.972  ,27.9888 ,69.972  ,132.9468,
209.916 ,209.916...209.916 goes 59 times... ] and target = 5001

Comment: @RajKumarPandit In any case, please see the answer that I posted before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use integer linear programming where each variable is a binary that corresponds to a number and represents whether that number is included in the result. It solves two problems, the first approaching the target value from below and the second from above and then takes the best solution. The following is an example implementation using [PuLP](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/):

```py
import numpy as np
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpMinimize, LpProblem, lpSum, LpVariable


rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
numbers = rng.integers(1, 10**6, size=10**4)
target = int(numbers.mean() * rng.normal(loc=1, scale=0.1))

indices = range(len(numbers))
variables = LpVariable.dicts("Choice", indices, cat="Binary")

leq_prob = LpProblem('leq', LpMaximize)
geq_prob = LpProblem('geq', LpMinimize)

leq_prob += lpSum([variables[i]*numbers[i] for i in indices]) <= target
leq_prob += lpSum([variables[i]*numbers[i] for i in indices])

geq_prob += lpSum([variables[i]*numbers[i] for i in indices]) >= target
geq_prob += lpSum([variables[i]*numbers[i] for i in indices])

leq_prob.solve()
leq_choices = [numbers[i] for i in indices if variables[i].value() == 1]

if sum(leq_choices) == target:
    solution = leq_choices
else:
    geq_prob.solve()
    geq_choices = [numbers[i] for i in indices if variables[i].value() == 1]

    solution = (
        leq_choices
        if target-sum(leq_choices) <= sum(geq_choices)-target
        else geq_choices
    )

print(f'Solution: {solution}')
print(f'Sum: {sum(solution)} (target: {target})')
```

Comment: How could you constraint this to use the fewest `numbers`?

Comment: I thought of a hack to do this, by just adding (`0.0001`) to each `number` in the beginning and then subtracting `0.0001` again from the solution, but it would be nice to know a more legitimate way to do this.

Comment: You mean that among all the possible solutions which yield the same "best" sum (i.e. the sum that is closest to the `target`) you want to choose a solution which uses the fewest numbers? This can be done as a two stage process. During the first stage, the best sum is determined, similar to the above answer. Then during the second stage you can solve another linear problem which constrains the sum of all chosen numbers to be that best sum and minimizes the number of numbers used: `num_prob += lpSum([variables[i]*numbers[i] for i in indices]) == sum(solution); num_prob += lpSum(variables)`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that's what I meant. Can you check if the answer I posted is correct/ what you meant? I have done a couple examples and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (in case you need a solution with the fewest numbers) thanks to @a_guest and the answer above:

```
def lp(numbers, target):

    numbers = [n for n in numbers if n <= target]
    indices = range(len(numbers))
    variables = LpVariable.dicts("Choice", indices, cat="Binary")

    leq_prob = LpProblem("leq", LpMaximize)
    geq_prob = LpProblem("geq", LpMinimize)

    leq_prob += lpSum([variables[i] * numbers[i] for i in indices]) <= target
    leq_prob += lpSum([variables[i] * numbers[i] for i in indices])

    geq_prob += lpSum([variables[i] * numbers[i] for i in indices]) >= target
    geq_prob += lpSum([variables[i] * numbers[i] for i in indices])

    leq_prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))
    leq_choices = [numbers[i] for i in indices if variables[i].value() == 1]

    if sum(leq_choices) == target:
        solution = leq_choices
    else:
        geq_prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))
        geq_choices = [numbers[i] for i in indices if variables[i].value() == 1]

        solution = (
            leq_choices
            if target - sum(leq_choices) <= sum(geq_choices) - target
            else geq_choices
        )

    # Stage 2
    num_prob = LpProblem("eq", LpMinimize)
    num_prob += lpSum([variables[i] * numbers[i] for i in indices]) == sum(solution)
    num_prob += lpSum(variables)
    num_prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))

    solution = [numbers[i] for i in indices if variables[i].value() == 1]

    print(f"Solution: {solution}")
    print(f"Sum: {sum(solution)} (target: {target})")
    return solution, target
```

Example:

```
numbers = [1, 99, 25, 55, 20]
target = 100
lp(numbers, target)
```

Gives:

```
Solution: [1, 99]
Sum: 100 (target: 100)
```

Comment: Before it gave: Solution: [25, 55, 20]